# Will guru approach me if I read guru charitra for a fixed number of times?

Tags: scripture, guru, dattatreya

I heard from one of my well-wishers that If I read [Sri Guru Charitra](https://book.gitapress.org/product-style-5/%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B7%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D-%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%9C%E0%A4%B0-2/) a fixed number of times then a guru will surely approach me.

Is it true according to the scriptures?

If yes, then how many times do I need to read? Are there any language restrictions?